# ワードプレスのテーマ REALITYのDemo Themeの反映が上手くいきません

Tags: php, wordpress

はじめて投稿させて頂きます。宜しくお願い致します。

現在ワードプレスを使って不動産のポータルサイトを構築しております。

サーバーは、Z.comの海外版を利用しており、ワードプレスをインストールしました。
外部テンプレートを購入しており、その親テーマと子テーマをワードプレスへアップロード致しました。

テーマは、[REALITY](https://themeforest.net/item/reality-real-estate-wordpress-theme/21627776)です。

このテーマにImport demo dataがありましたので、インポートをしてみたところ、プロセスが31%で止まったままで一行に進みません。サポート経由で問い合わせしたところ、php.iniファイルを下記の通り設定する様にと教えて頂けたのですが、それでも解決することが出来ずにいます。

> You can try it
>
> 1/ if you install theme in localhost. You can go to php.ini and set
>
> max_execution_time=5500
>
> max_input_time=5600
>
> memory_limit=1280M
>
> post_max_size=256M
>
> upload_max_filesize=756M
>
> max_file_uploads=20
>
> allow_url_fopen=On
>
> 2/ If you install theme in hosting you set this code in the config.php file
>
> *define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '500M');*
>
> *set_time_limit(800);*
>
> Then you can try import demo data again.
>
> I hope it help you.
>
> Finally if you still can not import the data, send me wp-admin & ftp
> account. I will help you.

Z.comのディレクトリには、user.iniファイルがありましたので、パーミッションを確認の上、上記の内容の通り設定しサーバーにあげてみましたが、変わりませんでした。

ワードプレス上では、未だこのままの状態です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

御手数ではございますが、なにか解決方法がございましたら、ご教示頂けますと助かります。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: インストール先がホスティングサービスであるなら、実施するのはサポートから回答のあった 2) の`config.php`を編集する方ではないでしょうか。

Comment: cubick様、コメントありがとうございます。こちらでも色々再度試してみます。

Comment: 無事反映出来ました。ご親切にありがとうございました。

Comment: 私のコメントと ganapati さんの回答ではそれぞれ手順が異なります。最終的にどんな方法で解決できたのかを分かるようにしてもらうと、他の人にも参考になると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max_execution_time　の設定についてはZ.comのサポートに聞くのが一番です。

私も海外テーマをいろいろ使ってきましたが、まずはdemo.○○○.comのようなテストドメインを作ってそこで設定を試し、すべてうまくいったら本番ドメインに設定をインポートすると楽です。

さて、そのうえで試していただきたいことですが、

１．テストサイトを再度立ち上げてmax_execution_timeを修正したうえでインポートしたどうなるか？

２．Wordpressのインポートプラグインがインストールされ有効になっているか？

３．demoデータのインポート作業時間帯をずらしたらどうなるか？

を確認・試していただけたらと思います。

海外テーマのインポート元のサーバーが混みあっていると失敗することも多いです。

何度か試すしかありません。

Comment: ganapati 様 ご親切にありがとうございます。頂きました内容を元にこちらで試してみます。

Comment: 無事反映出来ました。ご親切にありがとうございました。